# Calling python multiprocessing map function with a dictionary

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I can do the following with `imap`:

```
import multiprocessing

def function(a):
    return a**2

b = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
vals = pool.imap(function, b)

for i in vals:
    print(i)
```

However, if I want to pass in a dict, can this be done:

```
import multiprocessing

def function(name, a):
    print("{}'s number squared:".format(name))
    return a**2

b = dict(bob=1, dave=2, stan=3)

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
vals = pool.imap(function, b)

for i in vals:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a dictionary, but a `map` operation over a dictionary only provides the dictionary *keys*. If you want the items in the dictionary, use `dict.items`, so something like:

```
import multiprocessing
def function(item):
    name, a = item
    print("{}'s number squared:".format(name))
    return a**2

if __name__ == '__main__': # you must guard your multiprocessing calls!

    b = dict(bob=1, dave=2, stan=3)

    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4) as pool:
        vals = pool.imap(function, list(b.items()))

        for i in vals:
            print(i)
```

Or, you can use `imap` if you want that same function signature to work:

```
import multiprocessing
def function(name, a):
    print("{}'s number squared:".format(name))
    return a**2

if __name__ == '__main__': # you must guard your multiprocessing calls!

    b = dict(bob=1, dave=2, stan=3)

    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4) as pool:
        vals = pool.starmap(function, list(b.items()))

    for i in vals:
        print(i)
```

Another approach is to use a global variable, and pass the dict directly to `pool.map`, although it may be a bit ugly:

```
import multiprocessing
def function(name):
    a = b[name]
    print("{}'s number squared:".format(name))
    return a**2

b = dict(bob=1, dave=2, stan=3)

if __name__ == '__main__': # you must guard your multiprocessing calls!


    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4) as pool:
        vals = pool.imap(function, b)

        for i in vals:
            print(i)
```

Notice, I've used `muliprocessing.Pool` as a context manager, so when you leave the `with` block, the pool will be guaranteed to be closed, regardless of what happens. This is a best practice.

Answer (score -1):

You can't pass a dictionary, but you can pass a list of dictionaries like so:

```
import multiprocessing

def function(input_dictionary):
    print("{}'s number squared:".format(input_dictionary['name']))
    return input_dictionary['number']**2

b = [ {'name' : 'bob', 'number' : 1},
      {'name' : 'dave', 'number' : 2},
      {'name' : 'stan', 'number' : 3}, ]


pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
vals = pool.imap(function, b)

for i in vals:
    print(i)
```